# Variable undefined as result of API call in JS

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to get the dataValues part of an JSON object that is returned by this function that is called by an API call:

```js
exports.findOne = (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    Users.findByPk(id)
        .then(data => {
            if(data){
                console.log("data: ", data);
                res.send(data);
            } else {
                res.status(404).send({
                    message: "Cannot find user with id=${id}"
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "Error retrieving Tutorial with id=" + id
            });
        });
};
```

This is the output for when I print out data:

```
findOne:  Login {
  dataValues: {
    ID: 20,
    username: 'phil_swift',
    email: 'philswift@flextape.com',
    password: '<ENCRYPTED>',
    account_type: 1,
    token: null,
    token_expiration: null,
    require_password_at_login: false
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    ID: 20,
    username: 'phil_swift',
    email: 'philswift@flextape.com',
    password: '<ENCRYPTED>',
    account_type: 1,
    token: null,
    token_expiration: null,
    require_password_at_login: false
  },
  uniqno: 1,
  _changed: Set(0) {},
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    raw: true,
    attributes: [
      'ID',
      'username',
      'email',
      'password',
      'account_type',
      'token',
      'token_expiration',
      'require_password_at_login'
    ]
  },
  isNewRecord: false
}
```

On the front end, when I perform this GET request, it returns undefined.

```js
const { dataValues } = await httpCommon.get("/" + this.state.user.userID);
console.log("dataValues: ", dataValues);
```

How come this happens and how can I fix this?

Comment: See what the response for your request is in your browser's network inspector first. That way you'll know if the issue is server side or in your client code.

Comment: I second @AKX's comment. Also, I would suggest that you "lean" the findOne object to turn in into a POJO. Don't know what you're using but mongoose has the `lean()` function. And I would use `res.json(data)` to send it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give credit to @codemonkey for giving me this suggestion which worked. I replaced `res.send(data)` with `res.json(data)`.